# Why does vim hide wrapped lines and prints multiple @s?

Tags: vim

By default, `vim` wraps lines but if they are really long, you may end up seeing only `@` characters on your screen. What is the name and purpose of this feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the name of the feature, but it's a holdover from the original Unix version of the vi editor. "@" lines will appear at the end of the display buffer when a wrapped line is too long to show, when part of the line would appear off-screen. IIRC (it's been 30 years since I used this specific feature), it was also used to delay loading of long lines until you needed them, even if they would be fully visible.

Back in the 300-baud modem days, waiting for a logical line that filled four or five physical lines would be frustrating. Depending on how you configured it, vi would postpone loading of lines until your cursor reached them. Only then would it load the line into the display buffer. This greatly sped up editing when you knew exactly which line you needed to edit. If lines 2 and 3 in the file were very long, and you knew when you opened the file that you needed to edit line 5, you could open the file, and type 5G to go to the target line without waiting for the lines in the middle to load.

There was also an option to reduce the usable portion of the 24-line display to a smaller number, so that you could simulate a screen with, say, only 10 physical display lines. This was also used to speed up editing over slow connections.

Answer (score 7):

`:help 'display'`

```
    lastline        When included, as much as possible of the last line
                    in a window will be displayed.  When not included, a
                    last line that doesn't fit is replaced with "@" lines.
```

You can use `:set display+=lastline` to display as much content as possible in a window